# Tag Profile in MySites does not list externally tagged website

Tags: my-site, tagging, content-rating

In Sharepoint 2010 MySites, opening the Tag Profile for any tag seems to only list resources that have been tagged within Sharepoint (for example documents, blog pages etc). It doesn't list any external websites that have been tagged with the term. Even though I know websites have indeed been tagged (I can see them both inside user profiles, and also in the social tag section of User Profile service application.
This seems to defeat the purpose of the tag clouds etc somewhat, I had hoped that MySites 2010 could be used a 'delicious' like link and knowledge sharing tool - if the tag clouds only give you access to sharepoint based tags that that is no good to me.

Has anyone managed to get external websites to list in the Tag Profile page? (I have the same issue on multiple 2010 servers).

Comment: I duplicated the issue in my lab.  I thought I saw this work before.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found my own answer... from: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608006.aspx

Security trimming
Adding a tag, a note, or a rating to a Web page creates an activity. Before SharePoint Server displays an activity, it uses a component called the security trimmer to determine whether the current user has permission to view the Web page that the activity applies to. If the user is not permitted to view the Web page, SharePoint Server does not display the activity.

As the search service crawls Web pages, it records the permissions that are required to view each Web page. The security trimmer uses this information to determine whether a given user has permission to view a specific Web page. If the security trimmer has insufficient information to determine whether a user has permission to view a Web page, it errs on the side of caution and reports that the user does not have permission to view the Web page. As a result, if the search service has not crawled a Web page, activities that relate to that Web page will not be displayed.

Consider a custom security trimmer. If SharePoint Server’s security trimmer has insufficient information to determine whether a user has permission to view a Web page, it errs on the side of caution and reports that the user does not have permission. **One result of this behavior is that tags, notes, and ratings that are added to external Web sites are always trimmed.** If this behavior is not appropriate for your situation, consider implementing a custom security trimmer. For a sample custom security trimmer, see ISocialSecurityTrimmer Interface (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=188524&clcid=0x409).

Comment: @Jim no.. 6 months later and have still not got around to it. Too many other 'features' to address.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever implement a solution for this.  I was wondering how hard it would be to switch this so called feature off so that all external links do show up in the newsfeeds.  It seems kind of useless without it.